# How to tell if my range of cells is visible

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010

The following code is used to process a range of cells selected by the user:

```
ForEach (var cell in sheet.Range[string.Format("A{0}:A{1}", row1, row2)].Cells)
{
    // if this cell contains a specific value do something with the row
    if((cell.Value ?? "").ToString() == "1")
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem is, some of the rows in the range might have been hidden by a filter.

How can I ensure that I am only processing cells which are visible?

Answer (score 2):

`If Not sheet.Range(cell, cell).Hidden Then`...

In VB.Net. Can't seem to find whether the `Cell` object has a hidden property, but the `Range` object does. According to the MSDN, it returns a Boolean value as an object type. should be easy enough to convert to C#, I'm just not familiar enough with it to comfortably post a solution using it.

Comment: Hmm no can't access `Hidden` for some reason. `Unable to get the Hidden property of the Range class.`

Comment: I found out why though. To access `Hidden` you need to specify EntireRow, e.g. `Cell.EntireRow.Hidden`, then it is accessible. :)